# pubnub get history from multiple channels

Tags: react-native, notifications, chat, pubnub

I am using pubnub for chat , and using userid as channel to send messages , however when i want to retrieve conversation between two users , i need to get data from both channels, how can i do that?

I have data on both channels e.g. "userAid" and "userBid" but if i query

````
this.pubnub.history(
            { channel: ['userAid,'userBid'], reverse: true, count: 15 },
            (status, res) => {
            });```
it does not return any result  , if i query with only one channel it works
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The History SDK call is generally meant to fetch history from a single channel. If you need to fetch history from multiple channels, you need to use Batch History methods.

Refer to https://www.pubnub.com/docs/react-native-javascript/api-reference-storage-and-playback#batch-history for more details.

An example call might be as follows, but the link above provides a list of all the parameters that can be set. Please note that the ***fetchMessages*** method can be used to fetch history from a single channel as well.

```
pubnub.fetchMessages(
    { 
        channels: ['ch1', 'ch2', 'ch3'], 
        start: "15343325214676133",
        end: "15343325004275466",
        count: 25 
    }, 
    (status, response) => {
        // handle response
    }
);
```

Comment: Fetch messages allow to add multiple channels but at the time of getting messages from channel it allow one by one not simultaneously so how can we do it using the same method.

Comment: @AshishJain It does return messages from all the channels in one response. Check https://www.pubnub.com/docs/react-native-javascript/api-reference-storage-and-playback#batch-history-returns for how the response looks.

Comment: Yes, we can pass multiple channels but I am checking this one
https://www.pubnub.com/docs/android-java/api-reference-storage-and-playback
where they added condition for one channel like
 for (PNFetchMessageItem messageItem : channels.get("my_channel")) {}
so how can we retrieve for other channel response as well in single response?

Answer (score 1):

It seems history can only get messages from one channel.

Try this:

```
pubnub.fetchMessages({
  channels: ['ch1', 'ch2', 'ch3'],
  start: '15343325214676133',
  end: '15343325004275466',
  count: 15,
}, (status, response) => {
  // handle status, response
});
```

Pubnub docs on getting the history:
https://www.pubnub.com/developers/chat-resource-center/docs/reference/message-history